# Code snippet not working in Google Chrome

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I keep creating answers to things and using the very hand code snippet function. The problem is that the snippets don't run in Google Chrome and throw this error in console:

> The XSS Auditor refused to execute a script in 'http://stacksnippets.net/js' because its source code was found within the request. The auditor was enabled as the server sent neither an 'X-XSS-Protection' nor 'Content-Security-Policy' header.

Here's an example of one just created: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30077962/2117156

This seems to work in Firefox absolutely fine, however I'd rather not have to keep including JSFiddle links in my answers to cover a broken snippet.

Oh and I created the fiddle in Chrome, so it's not the code at fault.

***Update 1***

It doesn't work in IE either:

> SEC7130: Potential cross-site scripting detected in 'http://stacksnippets.net/js'. The content has been modified by the XSS Filter.

Clicking `SEC7130` takes to you to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-GB&k=k(VS.WebClient.Help.SEC7130)).

***Update 2***

The headers I am getting:

```
**General**
Remote Address:198.252.206.24:80
Request URL:http://stacksnippets.net/js
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK

**Response Headers**
Cache-Control:public, max-age=42
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:766
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 06 May 2015 14:55:23 GMT
Expires:Wed, 06 May 2015 14:56:06 GMT
Last-Modified:Wed, 06 May 2015 14:55:06 GMT
Vary:*
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET

**Request Headers**
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:2744
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:stacksnippets.net
Origin:http://stackoverflow.com
Referer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30077202/find-next-previous-element/30077962
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36
```

They also work if there is no JavaScript in the snippet...

Comment: Which version and OS? The snippet which you have in the link of your answer words perfectly in Chrome 42.0.2311.135 m, with OS windows.

Comment: I am running the same version of Chrome (latest), with windows 7

Comment: Same as Jamie; also works for me. About to check on a Mac.

Comment: Works on OS X Yosemite (10.10.2) with version 42.0.2311.135 of Chrome.

Comment: @BSMP What's your security level in Internet Options > Security?

Comment: It has the recommended/default Security settings (for both).

Comment: I definitely can see the `X-XSS-Protection: 0` header in the snippet's response. Is your Chrome going through a proxy that can eat that header?

Comment: Potentially the firewall at my work place is stripping out the header, although I just got someone to do a check and apparently nothing is being flagged... A month or so ago it was working fine.

Comment: Working just fine here. (Win 8.1 / Chrome 42)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I have added the headers I am getting.

Comment: @Jamie, since it works with Firefox in your case, can you confirm the response headers you get with Firefox do contain `X-XSS-Protection: 0`?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I can confirm that Firefox does **not** contain that header.

Comment: _If_ my firewall **is** taking out that header, I'm quite happy for it to do so as it's a security risk. I don't want some intrepid website to be able to just throw a header at me so it can get around browser security, that's just ridiculous. I'm not suggesting SO would do such a thing, but the methods certainly need looking at by the developers.

Comment: @Jamie, that's probably not your firewall, otherwise all your browsers would be affected. Maybe one of the add-ons you have installed on Firefox is responsible. Running with add-ons disabled would tell for sure.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Works in Firefox safe mode...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It's not Firefox that's the problem, it works in Firefox. It's Google Chrome and IE where it doesn't work.

Comment: @Jamie, ah, sorry, got mixed up while replying. That will teach me to do a bazillion things at the same time. The problem remains open, then :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Not a problem. If it is a header thing, ultimately there's a problem in that Firefox allows it. Allowing XSS is **bad**...